# Scatterpie doesn't recognize column name from data

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatterpie

I want to plot 8 data points using `scatterpie`. However, the function is throwing an error that it can't find the object corresponding to the column with values for y-coordinates.

### My Data

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scatterpie)

my_df <- structure(list(day_in_july = 13:20, yes_and_yes = c(0.611814345991561, 
0.574750830564784, 0.593323216995448, 0.610539845758355, 0.650602409638554, 
0.57429718875502, 0.575971731448763, 0.545454545454545), yes_but_no = c(0.388185654008439, 
0.425249169435216, 0.406676783004552, 0.389460154241645, 0.349397590361446, 
0.42570281124498, 0.424028268551237, 0.454545454545455)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))  

> my_df

## # A tibble: 8 x 3
## day_in_july yes_and_yes yes_but_no
##         <int>       <dbl>      <dbl>
## 1          13       0.612      0.388
## 2          14       0.575      0.425
## 3          15       0.593      0.407
## 4          16       0.611      0.389
## 5          17       0.651      0.349
## 6          18       0.574      0.426
## 7          19       0.576      0.424
## 8          20       0.545      0.455
```

### Plotting the data using scatterpie fails

I followed the code from the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterpie/vignettes/scatterpie.html), but it still isn't working for me.

```r
ggplot() + 
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x = day_in_july, y = yes_but_no), 
                           data = my_df, 
                           cols = colnames(my_df)[2:3])  


## Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'yes_but_no' not found
```

**I've tried converting from `tibble` to a `data.frame` beforehand, but didn't solve the problem.**

---

By the way, setting `y` as a constant (e.g., `2`) works:

```r
ggplot() + 
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x = day_in_july, y = 2), 
                           data = my_df, 
                           cols = colnames(my_df)[2:3])  + 
  coord_fixed()
```

[image: works]

### But this is not what I want. Rather, I want the y-value each pie chart is centered at to correspond to the 'yes_but_no' proportion for that specific pie chart

Comment: I also get the same error message and do not know what to suggest except to contact the package maintainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because you recycled the same column for the `y` mapping & pie columns.

The underlying code for `geom_scatterpie` does some data manipulations to pivot/gather (depending on the terminology of your tidyr package) the dataframe to long form, so the `yes_but_no` column no longer exists on its own by the time ggplot tries to plot the finalised data. The following would work:

```
my_df$y <- my_df$yes_but_no # create a duplicate column

ggplot() + 
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x = day_in_july, y = y), 
                  data = my_df, 
                  cols = colnames(my_df)[2:3])
```

For better appearance, you can apply equal coordinates while spacing out the y positions:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x = day_in_july, y = y*100), # space y positions out
                  data = my_df, 
                  cols = colnames(my_df)[2:3]) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "yes but no",
                     labels = function(x) x/100) + # maintain original y labels
  coord_fixed()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Do you know how I could horizontally space out the plot, so it will become more wide than tall?

Comment: Maybe expand y by a multiple of 10 (& change its labels accordingly) instead of 100?