# How to add a line to connect between pies in a scatterpie plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatterpie

I have a scatterpie plot with pies plotted over x and y axes. How can I add straight lines that connect between pies? Ideally, I would want the lines to connect the y-values underlying the center points of the pies.

I tried adding `geom_path` but it didn't work out.

This question is a follow-up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63068645/adding-percents-for-pie-proportions-in-each-piechart-in-scatterpie-plot?noredirect=1&lq=1) question I posted before.

### My Data

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scatterpie)

my_df <- structure(list(day_in_july = 13:20, yes_and_yes = c(0.611814345991561, 
0.574750830564784, 0.593323216995448, 0.610539845758355, 0.650602409638554, 
0.57429718875502, 0.575971731448763, 0.545454545454545), yes_but_no = c(0.388185654008439, 
0.425249169435216, 0.406676783004552, 0.389460154241645, 0.349397590361446, 
0.42570281124498, 0.424028268551237, 0.454545454545455), y = c(0.388185654008439, 
0.425249169435216, 0.406676783004552, 0.389460154241645, 0.349397590361446, 
0.42570281124498, 0.424028268551237, 0.454545454545455)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

### My current scatterpie plot

```r
p <- ggplot(data = my_df) +
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x = day_in_july, y = y*50, r = 0.3), 
                  data = my_df, 
                  cols = colnames(my_df)[2:3],
                  color = "red") + 
  geom_text(aes(y = y*50, x = day_in_july, 
                label = paste0(formatC(y*100, digits = 3), "%")),
            nudge_y = 0.07, nudge_x = -0.25, size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(y = y*50, x = day_in_july, 
            label = paste0(formatC((1-y)*100, digits = 3), "%")),
            nudge_y = -0.07, nudge_x = 0.25, size = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("pink", "seagreen3")) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = xvals, breaks = xvals) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "yes but no",
                     labels = function(x) x/50) + 
  coord_fixed()

> p
```

[image: scatterpie]

---

### I want to connect the pies to express a trend over time, such as the following:

[image: scatterpie_connected]

- Basically, I want to connect the y-values behind each pie, in a way that the line will be behind the pies.
- I tried adding `geom_path()`. But it didn't work and I just get the same plot with no line. Also tried `geom_line` without success.

```r
p + geom_path(x = as.numeric(my_df$day_in_july), y = my_df$yes_but_no)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `geom_path` with the same `x` and `y` aesthetics at the beginning of your code:

```
p <- ggplot(data = my_df) +
  geom_path(aes(x = day_in_july, y = y*50)) +
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x = day_in_july, y = y*50, r = 0.3), 
                  data = my_df, 
                  cols = colnames(my_df)[2:3],
                  color = "red") + 
  geom_text(aes(y = y*50, x = day_in_july, 
                label = paste0(formatC(y*100, digits = 3), "%")),
            nudge_y = 0.07, nudge_x = -0.25, size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(y = y*50, x = day_in_july, 
                label = paste0(formatC((1-y)*100, digits = 3), "%")),
            nudge_y = -0.07, nudge_x = 0.25, size = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("pink", "seagreen3")) +
  # scale_x_continuous(labels = xvals, breaks = xvals) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "yes but no",
                     labels = function(x) x/50) + 
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! You made me realize that the position of `geom_path()` in the ggplot code structure affects whether it's behind or on top of the pies. Awesome.